# How to echo the total of increment counter?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

The $counter variable is working fine counting the loop, but I need to get the total amount of elements for each loop. How would I go about doing that?

```
<div id="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" class="lity-hide resource-pop-up">
<?php 
  if($the_posts->have_posts()): 
    $counter = 1;
    while($the_posts->have_posts()):
      $the_posts->the_post();

    //vars
    $section_one     = apply_filters('the_content', get_field('section_one'));
    $section_two     = apply_filters('the_content', get_field('section_two'));
    $learn_more_link = get_field('learn_more_link');
?>
  <section class="pop-up">
    <div class="title">
      <div class="brand">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/125x125" alt="Brand">
        <?php the_title('<h3>','</h3>'); ?>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <h4><?php echo $counter; ?>/<?php echo $counter->length; ?></h4>
      </aside>

    </div>

    <div class="row pop-up-content">
      <aside class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <?php echo $section_one; ?>
      </aside>

      <aside class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <?php echo $section_one; ?>
      </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="learn-more"><a href="<?php echo $learn_more_link ?>" target="_blank">Learn More</a></div>
  </section>
  <?php
    $counter++;
      endwhile; 
      wp_reset_postdata();
    endif; 
  ?>
</div>
```

I should expect (number of element)/(total number of elements) or 2/10, basically like saying 2 of 10.

Comment: For the number of posts, it may be `$the_posts->post_count` as opposed to `$counter->length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the number of posts, you need

```
echo $the_posts->post_count
```

which is a total of all the posts, as opposed to

```
echo $counter->length
```

`$counter` is only a number and wouldn't have a length property anyway.